# get byte or image from Crypto Service Provider

Tags: vb.net, encryption

I used This Code To Encrypt and Decrypt Data In my application 
but the code use File Stream to do all work This is the code :

```
    Dim bytKey As Byte()
    Dim bytIV As Byte()
    bytKey = CreateKey("mrbrashad1999")
    bytIV = CreateIV("mrbrashad1999")

    Try 'In case of errors.

        'Setup file streams to handle input and output.
        fsInput = New System.IO.FileStream(strInputFile, FileMode.Open, _
                                           FileAccess.Read)
        fsOutput = New System.IO.FileStream(strOutputFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, _
                                            FileAccess.Write)
        fsOutput.SetLength(0) 'make sure fsOutput is empty

        'Declare variables for encrypt/decrypt process.
        Dim bytBuffer(4096) As Byte 'holds a block of bytes for processing
        Dim lngBytesProcessed As Long = 0 'running count of bytes processed
        Dim lngFileLength As Long = fsInput.Length 'the input file's length
        Dim intBytesInCurrentBlock As Integer 'current bytes being processed
        Dim csCryptoStream As CryptoStream
        'Declare your CryptoServiceProvider.
        Dim cspRijndael As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
        'Setup Progress Bar
        'pbStatus.Value = 0
        'pbStatus.Maximum = 100

        'Determine if ecryption or decryption and setup CryptoStream.
        Select Case Direction
            Case CryptoAction.ActionEncrypt
                csCryptoStream = New CryptoStream(fsOutput, cspRijndael.CreateEncryptor(bytKey, bytIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            Case CryptoAction.ActionDecrypt
                csCryptoStream = New CryptoStream(fsOutput, cspRijndael.CreateDecryptor(bytKey, bytIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        End Select

        'Use While to loop until all of the file is processed.
        While lngBytesProcessed < lngFileLength
            'Read file with the input filestream.
            intBytesInCurrentBlock = fsInput.Read(bytBuffer, 0, 4096)
            'Write output file with the cryptostream.
            csCryptoStream.Write(bytBuffer, 0, intBytesInCurrentBlock)
            'Update lngBytesProcessed
            lngBytesProcessed = lngBytesProcessed + CLng(intBytesInCurrentBlock)
            'Update Progress Bar
            'pbStatus.Value = CInt((lngBytesProcessed / lngFileLength) * 100)
        End While

        'Close FileStreams and CryptoStream.
        csCryptoStream.Close()
        fsInput.Close()
        fsOutput.Close()

        'Catch file not found error.
    Catch When Err.Number = 53 'if file not found
        MsgBox("Please check to make sure the path and filename" + _
                "are correct and if the file exists.", _
                 MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Invalid Path or Filename")

        'Catch all other errors. And delete partial files.
    Catch
        fsInput.Close()
        fsOutput.Close()


    End Try
```

what i should do to get byte() or image From encrypted data in my file system direct to my application variable .

Answer (score 0):

A `CryptoStream` simply sits on top of another `Stream`.  When you `Write` to the `CryptoStream`, it takes the `Byte` array that you pass in, encrypts it and populates another array with the result, then it will `Write` that to the underlying `Stream`.  Likewise, when you call `Read` it will call `Read` on the underlying `Stream`, decrypt it and then pass you the result.  In your case you are using a `FileStream` but it can be any type of `Stream` at all, e.g. `NetworkStream` or `GZipStream`.  If you want a temporary place to store binary data within your app then you can use a `MemoryStream`.  The code to use the `Stream` is the same regardless of its type.